# How to check if my foreach loop has a bug?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I was just quickly throwing together a script for an article website where I retrieve articles out of a database.

Here is my index.php script

```
    <?php
    // include header
    require("include/header.php");
    require("include/helperfunctions.inc.php");
    ?>

    <!-- page content -->
    <!-- left section -->
    <section id="contentleft">
<?php require("include/functions.php"); 
displayArticles();
foreach ($articles as $article) : ;
?>
<h2>Recent Articles</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo htmlout($articles['id']) ; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo htmlout($articles['title']) ; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo htmlout($articles['summary']) ; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </section>

    <!-- right content -->
    <section id="contentright">

    </section>

    <?php
    // include footer
    require("include/footer.php");
    ?>
```

Here is the start of the function library

```
    function displayArticles($order="publicationdate DESC"){
        // connect to the database
        include("include/db.inc.php");
    $query = "SELECT id, title, summary FROM maths order by ". $order . " limit 10";

// query the database
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    // error checking
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    // $error = "error fetching articles";
    echo " could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . " ";
    exit();     
}
// loop through storing values into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $articles[] = array('id'=>$row['id'] , 'title'=>$row['title'],'summary'=>$row['summary']);        
}

    }

    ?>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\include\functions.php on line 17 Recent Articles Notice: Undefined variable: articles in C:\Apache24\htdocs\home.php on line 14 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\home.php on line 14

Comment: ...What's wrong with it? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\include\functions.php on line 17 
Recent Articles


Notice: Undefined variable: articles in C:\Apache24\htdocs\home.php on line 14

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\home.php on line 14

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Hope you can see the 3 warnings.

Comment: That was definitely a big help, Connor.

Comment: `$article['id']` instead of `$articles['id']`

Comment: The `mysqli_fetch_array` error means your query is failing. Have a look into mysqli error handling (you're checking for a connection error, but not after a connection attempt, rather after a query attempt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a scope issue with the $articles object. You create $articles in the displayArticles() function.. but outside of the function, your other code does not know about it. Try returning $articles inside displayArticles(), and replace your displayArticles(); call at the top of the first page with:

```
$articles = displayArticles();
```

Also, as panique in the comments pointed out, you are referencing the wrong object inside your foreach block. Remove the 's' at the end of each $articles[blah], so that it reads $article[blah].

Comment: Thanks! I just added this line .. return $articles[];.                          Now i get this error Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\Apache24\htdocs\include\functions.php on line 24.

Comment: Remove the brackets ( return $articles; ).

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, I appreciate the help.. I've fixed the bugs I think and inserted error checking... Now I get this error, Notice: Undefined index: summary in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 18. I've researched on google and can't seem to find anything. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ah, check out this page for understanding what an index in an array is:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ; Index in this context (of PHP arrays) is just another word for key :) And you are no bother at all to me, I am glad to be able to help. Others might tell you to brush up on the basics of programming (arrays, functions, scope, etc).. it'll take more time up front, but reading PHP.net and wikipedia about these concepts will answer these and future questions, which is in the spirit of stackoverflow: do a lot of your own research.. then come here with what you've tried :)